# Make IDE start parenthesis in second line

Tags: unity-game-engine, format

When I create a new Unity script, it contains this stub:

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start (){

}
```

I always find myself rewriting it to

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start ()
{

}
```

because I find it easier to read.

I tried to find a settings under Tools->Option to have the IDE do that automatically by default, but I didn't find any.

Can this be achieved easily automatically somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not from Visual Studio but from the script template used by Unity when you create a new script.

Modify that script template and give the left curly braces new line for both the `Start` and `Update` functions.

The file is named *"81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs.txt"* and you can find it at the path below:

**Windows**: *C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Resources\ScriptTemplates*

**Mac**: */Applications/Unity/Editor/Data/Resources/ScriptTemplates*

**Mac** (since 5.2.1f1): */Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Resources/ScriptTemplates*

---

**1**.Open the *"81-C# Script-NewBehaviourScript.cs.txt"* file with Notepad. It should look something like this:

[image]

**2**.Position your mouse caret exactly before the `Start` function's **left** curly braces then press the *Enter* **once**. After that, press the *Space* key **4** times. Do the-same thing for the Update function then save it.

[image]

That's it. You don't have to restart Unity. This changes should take effect when you create another new script.

Note:

Don't change or rename anything else in that file.

Comment: How do you know so well even for different platforms? You're not a Unity intern programmer, are you?

Comment: You can find the location of the Unity Script Templates in the [support](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/210223733-How-to-customize-Unity-script-templates) page. I don't work for Unity and I am not associated with them. I simply use Unity for my daily work and most of my answers are here because I've ran into these problems in the past.